# Understanding the concept of string slicing in python

Tags: python, string

This might be a noob question but am not an expert in programming. I am having a hard time grasping the concept. Any help/explanation would be appriciated.

If `str1 = 'hello'`
and we want to know `str1[-1]`.

Shouldn't the answer be - out of bound/error and not 'o'?
Why is it 'o'? Can anyone explain me the reason behind it? The book is very unclear about it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the _reason_ why python allows negative numbers in slices, but if I had to guess I'd say it's because they're useful.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot more sense now. -1 was referring to the last item in the array of the string.

Comment: You can imagine the indices as a circular tape with numbers. 0 represents the first element, 1 the second and so on. If you look at the tape in the reverse order -1 is the last element, -2 the one before the last. example st = 'abcd' st[-1] = 'd'   st[-2] = 'c'